# Why DrawArc/DrawPie angle point differs from actual Arc point for the same angle?

Tags: c#, algorithm, system.drawing, angle, ellipse

When I draw an Ellipse or an Arc using C# DrawArc/DrawEllipse or DrawPie GDI functions, I believed that it draws for the exact angle what I have given. But, when I did a test on it by  writing a small program, I found 225 degrees sweep angle in DrawArc is actually not 225 degrees in view. My test rogram draws a line from 0 degree to 360 degree every second (like a clock seconds hand) and in parallel Drawing arc using DrawArc function for the same angle.

Below function is used to get point on angle given start/end point and angle. Can somebody please explain whyis this difference? I tried to find the end point of the drawn arc by DrawArc(). I can achieve it in different way. But, I dont understand why the DrawArc function is working this way? 0, 90, 180, 270, 360 angles are fine with DrawArc.

```
public static Point PointOnEllipseFromAngle(Point center, int radiusX, int radiusY, int angle)
    {
        double x = center.X + radiusX * Math.Cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180.0));
        double y = center.Y + radiusY * Math.Sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180.0));
        return new Point((int)x, (int)y);
    }
```

Form Paint goes like this

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = Bounds;
        rect.Inflate(-50, -50);
        // Mid point
        Point mid = new Point(rect.Left+(rect.Width / 2), rect.Top+(rect.Height / 2));

        // Arc point for the given angle (angle is incremented in timer every second)
        Point p1 = PointOnEllipseFromAngle(new Point(rect.Left+(rect.Width / 2), rect.Top+(rect.Height / 2)), rect.Width / 2, rect.Height / 2, angle); 

        // Line between mid and arc point
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Blue, 2), mid, p1);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(angle.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 18), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), p1);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new Rectangle(p1.X - 5, p1.Y - 5, 10, 10)); // red circle at edge of the line

        // DrawArc for the same angle
        e.Graphics.DrawArc(new Pen(Color.Green,2), rect, 0, angle);

        // Just Drawing axis lines (horizontal, vertical, diagonal)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), mid, new Point(rect.Left+rect.Width,rect.Top+(rect.Height/2)));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), mid, new Point(rect.Left, rect.Top + (rect.Height / 2)));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), mid, new Point(rect.Left + (rect.Width/2), rect.Top + rect.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), mid, new Point(rect.Left + (rect.Width / 2), rect.Top));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), rect.Left,rect.Top,rect.Right,rect.Bottom);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 2), rect.Left, rect.Bottom, rect.Right, rect.Top);

    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you asking if there's a bug in `DrawArc`? Or are you asking if there's a bug in your code that finds the point on the ellipse? Can you describe (or, better yet, show a picture) what you expect and what happens?

Comment: @JimMischel: I think as per the answer given by Matthias, the question is now about DrawArc() method - there is no bug in my code, but the DrawArc() function is working in a way differently than what it is supposed to do. Even there is no such explanation in MSDN about this!!! So whatever the rectangle you put as parameter for this function, it will give you only arc based on Circle compressed in that rectangle, not actual elliptic with correct angle in View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow DrawArc calculates the angles/drawing based on an arc with regular radius and it therefore takes the longer side. I could not find an explanation why it works this way, but maybe [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47611/is-it-a-bug-in-psellipticarc-or-is-my-calculation-wrong) helps.

[image: 45 degrees on regular arc]

```
        var radiusX = rect.Width/2;
        var radiusY = rect.Height/2;
        // Mid point
        var mid = new Point(rect.Left + (rect.Width/2), rect.Top + (rect.Height/2));

        int larger = Math.Max(radiusX, radiusY);

        // Arc point for the given angle (angle is incremented in timer every second)
        Point p1 = PointOnEllipseFromAngle(new Point(rect.Left + radiusX, rect.Top + radiusY), larger, larger, angle);
        //Point p1 = PointOnEllipseFromAngle(new Point(rect.Left + radiusX, rect.Top + radiusY), radiusX, radiusY, angle);
```

Comment: Thanks alot! You are right. I do care to find out why it works this way (design flaw?), but for now, atleast I know the reason which clears my mind :) Thank you very much.